# Какую html кодировку выбрать для webview?

Tags: android, кодировка, шрифты, webview

В приложении есть заготовленные html страницы. Когда тестирую на телефоне API 27 отображается все корректно, пробую на телефоне с API 19 вместо текста крокозябра, на эмуляторе API 19 тоже самое, а на эмуляторе API 22 вместо символов уже ромбики.
Кодировка в андройд студии установлена windows 1251. Подскажите как быть?

Comment: Все кодировки ненужная ересь, кроме utf-8

Comment: поставил utf-8, на API 24 работает, на API 19 не работает, сама студия вместо символов теперь показывает ромбы.

Comment: В html-странице кодировка прописана-то?

Comment: нет, с html знаком крайне поверхностно

Comment: Про кодировку в html можно посмотреть здесь: [Указываем кодировку текста документа](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML#%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0).